# Can I use CoreTelephony in my iPhone app without it being rejected from the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, appstore-approval, core-telephony

Can I use CoreTelephony in my iPhone app without it being rejected from the AppStore?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store" rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Situation has changed, some parts of CoreTelephony are

> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Check for details:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603

Answer (score 0):

No :)

You may not use private-frameworks like that in your application. They have robot-like machines that scan your binary on use of private-frameworks and automatically reject your app if you do. So, no, there's no way to do this.